# event.stopPropagation(); on mobile device with a Materialize dropdown?

Tags: jquery, mobile, materialize

I have a code that works perfectly on computers for my website. The aim, here, is to prevent the dropdown to hide when the user clicks on it. In fact, there is a form to connect to the user's personal space on this dropdown, so the user needs to click on the input fields.

I have been looking for a solution for hours and I can't figure out what's wrong. I think the browser on the mobile device doesn't catch the event but I didn't find anything to replace it.

Here is the html dropdown that is prevented from hiding :

```
          <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content list_acc_drop s12">

        <li id="header_co_first" class="header_co">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col s10 offset-s1">

              <h5 class="light-green-text text-darken-2">Connectez-vous</h5>

            </div>

          </div>

        </li>

        <form method="post" action="dashboard/Controleur/CONT_cnx.php" class="black-text">

        <li class="header_co"><div class="row">


          <div class="col s1">

            <i class="material-icons prefix icon_nav">person_outline</i>

          </div>
          <div class="col s9 offset-s1">

            <input placeholder="Utilisateur" id="user" type="text" class="validate in_co" name="user">

          </div>
        </div></li>

        <li class="header_co"><div class="row">
          <div class="col s1">

            <i class="material-icons prefix icon_nav">https</i>

          </div>
          <div class="col s9 offset-s1">

            <input placeholder="Mot de passe" id="passwd" type="password" class="validate in_co" name="passwd">

          </div>
        </div></li>


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s6 offset-s3">

         <button id="btn_co" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Connexion
         <i id="icon_co" class="material-icons right">send</i>
         </button>

        </div>
      </div>

      </form>

      </ul>
```

And here is the js code that does it :

```
    $("#dropdown2").click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

So that's it, I am trying to make it work on a mobile device. Thanks by advance, if you can help me :).

(PS : I already took a look at the others posts and didn't find what I need)

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle to your question? It will help.

Comment: Does it work with the CSS/JavaScript "Materialize" Framework on JSFiddle ? (Sorry I have never used this)

Comment: you can add the `css` and `JS` to it. Copy/Paste the [Materialize CDN](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html#download)

Comment: Hi, sorry I was so busy yesterday, I'll do the JSFiddle right now :).

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle ! Even if I delete the event.StopPropagation(); function on JSFiddle, it stays open (just a bug from JSFiddle I think). So just keep in mind that it hides and the aim is to make it stay visible on mobile device :). Thanks again by advance ! https://jsfiddle.net/Ytss/6x85oL21/